# Android Location returning null

Tags: java, android, gps, location

Having some trouble trying to determine longitude and latitude, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Hopefully someone will be willing to take a look, i've spent days trying to figure this out.

Have this in my manifest permissions ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

```
 private void comenzarLocalizacion()
    {

        locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        mostrarPosicion(loc);

        locListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                mostrarPosicion(location);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }

        };

        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 0, locListener);
    }

    private void mostrarPosicion(Location loc) {
        if(loc != null)
        {
            lblLatitud.setText("Latitud: " + String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()));
            lblLongitud.setText("Longitud: " + String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));
            lblPrecision.setText("Precision: " + String.valueOf(loc.getAccuracy()));
            Log.i("", String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude() + " - " + String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude())));


        }
        else
        {
            lblLatitud.setText("Latitud: (cannot be found)");
            lblLongitud.setText("Longitud: (cannot be found)");
            lblPrecision.setText("Precision: (cannot be found)");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> *#Precisely the best way to access location on is through (new) Fused Location Providers API*

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;

public class Locations extends IntentService implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {


    public Locations() {
        super("Locations");
        Log.d("Locations", "Location service started... ");
    }

    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LocationClient locationClient;
    private Location location;

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        locationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
     // do something on Location change.
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.w("Locations", "Location client connected...");

            // get last location
        location = locationClient.getLastLocation();
        Log.w("Locations", "Latitude : "+location.getLatitude() + "");
        Log.w("Locations", "Longitude : "+location.getLongitude() + "");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (locationClient.isConnected()) {
            locationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
        }
        locationClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
    }

}
```

*Source* https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Answer (score 0):

i am also face the same problem some time ago... actually LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER work if GPS is on in device few time ago otherwise this code not work so i am decided to get location with the help of LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER.....
may be it will help you
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177989/locationmanager-dont-get-the-right-results/20179234#20179234) I have given the code for getting the location. The code will first check the location via `GPS`. If `GPS` is not available it will use your network provider to get the coarse location. Try and let me know if it works.

Comment: this can precisely be a comment.