# get latitude and longitude in Android without show the map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-activity, google-maps-api-2

Is there a way to obtain information without displaying the map?
I want get my coordinate of my place during the work with other activity.
tnx a lot.

Comment: yes, you dont have to use a map to get the longitude and latitude

Comment: same question here with anwser
 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227292/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-mobiledevice-in-android

Comment: Link Mentioned above gives the best answer. Just adding to it, based on your requirement. you have to choose how many minutes once, you need the location information. Reason is listeners drain device battery more. So, choose a scenario appropriately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177989/locationmanager-dont-get-the-right-results/20179234#20179234

Answer (score 0):

By Using [`LocationManager`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) you can get lat and lang :

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

The call to `getLastKnownLocation()` doesn't block - which means it will return `null` if no position is currently available - so you probably want to have a look at passing a [`LocationListener`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) to the [`requestLocationUpdates()` method](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) instead, which will give you asynchronous updates of your location.

```
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
}

lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS, 2000, 10, locationListener);
```

You'll need to give your application the [`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) if you want to use GPS.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

You may also want to add the [`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) for when GPS isn't available and select your location provider with the [`getBestProvider()` method](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getBestProvider%28android.location.Criteria,%20boolean%29).

Answer (score 0):

> Using this code able to get latitude and Longitude values and make
>   sure before using application you got permission from manifest for accessing location

```
if(isGPS) {
    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try 
              {
                double lat=location.getLatitude();
            double lng=location.getLongitude(); 
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),lat+"and"+lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
              }
              catch (Exception e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
        }
                else
                {
            display("GPS not Enabled");
        }
Manifest permission
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use this if you want to get lat lon without internet

```
 LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        latitude = location.getLongitude();
        longitude = location.getLatitude();
```